# history commamd in RHEL8

Tags: rhel, command-history

what is the significance of serial number in output when we run "history" command in linux ?
For example :

```
1 cat 
2 cd
3 pwd
4 echo hii
5 history
```

Comment: Do you have an image?

Comment: They are sequence numbers, they go up by one each line.

Answer (score 3):

It's simply counting the number of commands ran since the `HISTFILE` was created.

So if your shell is configured to create a new `HISTFILE` on every login, the first command you ran after login will be numbered `1`.

You can also use this to re-run commands. For example, I want to run command number `1030` again in `bash`. I can simply do

```
!1030
```